# How to pass parameters to a Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash script as below, and I want it to read two dates as parameters, for example: `myshell date1 date2`. How do I assign parameters to variables `date1` and `date2`?

```
sed "s/$date1/$date2/g" wlacd_stat.xml >tmp.xml
mv tmp.xml wlacd_stat.xml
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You use `$1`, `$2` in your script. E.g:

```
date1="$1"
date2="$2"
sed "s/$date1/$date2/g" wlacd_stat.xml >temp.xml
mv temp.xml wlacd_stat.xml
```

Answer (score 9):

To iterate over the parameters, you can use this shorthand:

```
#!/bin/bash
for a
do
    echo $a
done
```

This form is the same as `for a in "$@"`.

Answer (score 8):

Bash arguments are named after their position.

Moreover, if you need to handle one argument after the other, you can shift them and always use `$1`:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    echo $1
    shift
done
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$0
$1
$2
```

And so on will contain the script name, then the first and the second line argument.