# How to get number cores and processors form params

Tags: shell

I'm new in shell scripts. I've got a sheduler, which start my script with `qsub -l nodes=a:ppn=b myscript.sh`. I need to get this `a` and `b` in `myscript.sh`. How can i get it?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters to a Linux Bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645636/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-linux-bash-script)

Comment: maybe you can be a bit more specific what values you expect as a and b - maybe someone can help you find out without herself knowing details about qsub? (no manpage for it on my debian)

Comment: @StefanHegny this params using to set value for node and process per node. In `myscript.sh` i'm using `#PBS -l nodes=$1:ppn=$2`, where `$1` and `$2` is `a` and `b` params from qsub

Comment: @Vanya, so you want to know how many cores are there? Or how they are called? Or if they are so fast that you could assign more than one worker? You might want to edit your question so that this becomes clear. I still don't understand if I might be able to help you...I see your title already goes into that direction

Comment: @StefanHegny i'm asking about number processors, which i got from params into `PBS -l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I've found the answer. In torque we have 2 variables for this. For get number of nodes u should use `nnodes = $PBS_UM_NODES`, for processors `nprocs = $PBS_NUM_PPN`

Answer (score 0):

Number of cores: e.g.

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo|grep -c processor
```

Not sure about the ppn nor about how to make a difference between cpus and cores though.