# shell script zins calculation

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, tax

I need a bash script that calculates basic tax.
It should be callable by

> tax.sh or with an optional parameter: tax.sh (capital or help) (interest rate) (duration)

What I have is that:

```
re='^-?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$'
echo "capital: "
read capital
if ![[ $capital =~ $re ]] ; then
  echo "invalid capital!" >&2; exit 1
fi
echo "rate: "
    read rate
    if ![[ $rate=~ $re ]] ; then
      echo "invalid rate!" >&2; exit 1
    fi
echo "duration: "
    read duration
    if ![[ $duration=~ $re ]] ; then
      echo "invalid duration!" >&2; exit 1
    fi
echo "the capital after "$duration" years is: "
echo "scale=5;($capital*($rate/100)*$duration)+$capital" | bc
```

I have no clue how to implement parameters or do the calculation right :/
The calculation is always a little bit smaller then it should be.

Comment: What is your question here? your script seems ok, except few syntax error instances leaving a space in `![[ $rate=~ $re ]] ;` to `! [[ $rate =~ $re ]] ;`

Comment: "The calculation is always a little bit smaller then it should be.". Examples?

Comment: e.g. 5000 1 5 should be 5255.05 but it is 5250 in the shell script. and the 2nd question is how I implement the parameters

Comment: @DimitriStrogatrov: What is the `$tax` variable doing in the calculation? It has not been read or set before?

Comment: sorry that actually was a typing error of me... i meant $rate there. happened when copying from putty...

Comment: I suspect the reason the answer is too small is because the formula assumes simple interest but compound interest is required.  A different formula must be used.  As for parameters, see [How to pass parameters to a Linux Bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2645636/4154375).

Answer (score 0):

> how to implement parameters

A way is to assign [positional parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html) to your variables and skip the `read` of each variable if the [parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) is not null; e. g.

```
capital=$1; ${capital:+:} read -p "capital: " capital
…
rate=$2; ${rate:+:} read -p "rate: " rate
…
duration=$3; ${duration:+:} read -p "duration: " duration
…
```

> do the calculation right

As pjh rightly wrote: "*the reason the answer is too small is because the formula assumes simple interest but compound interest is required. A different formula must be used.*" This is:

```
echo "scale=5;$capital*(1+$rate/100)^$duration" | bc
```