# Run shell script with argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

At the moment I am manually searching for three characters which can be anything in dir1 dir2 dir3 etc

By going grep -i -r abc dir1

then

grep -i -r abc dir2

grep -i -r abc dir3

etc

Trying to automate this somewhat and thought about writing a shell script, something like
search.sh

and then when I want to search for something in the above directories I can put the three letters that I'm searching for

For example: run search.sh $Mid = abc

The shell script would do something like this:

```
$mid = Mid;
grep -i -r $mid nab-prep1001 | grep -i -r $mid nab-prep1002 | grep -i -r $mid multi-account-bpay-report | grep -i -r $mid nab-prep1004 | grep -i -r $mid nab-prep100 | grep -i -r $mid nab-prep1006 | grep -i -r $mid nab-prep1007
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, but I think you just want `grep -ir abc dir1 dir2 dir3` or better yet `grep -ir abc dir{1..3}`.

Comment: Otherwise, this is a duplicate of [How to pass parameters to a Linux Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2645636/4518341)

Answer (score 2):

Very simple script and straightforward approach. Arguments are passed with `$n`, here n is number of the arguments 1,2,3 etc.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Simple Script"
echo "$1" "$2
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./simple.sh hello world
Simple Script
hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in arguments to a script and retrieve them as positional parameters inside your script.

So running:

```
./search.sh abc
```

You can access the argument "abc" with `$1` inside the script (assuming you are passing in a single parameter).

I would recommend simply reading up on Linux Script Arguments online.

Comment: Link: [Special Variable Types - TLDP](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html)